# What is the difference between pushReplacementNamed and popAndPushNamed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation

The `NavigatorState` class in `Flutter#navigator.dart` have 2 method with the similar behavior. What is the difference between `pushReplacementNamed` and `popAndPushNamed` in Flutter?

**`pushReplacementNamed`**

> Replace the current route of the navigator by pushing the route named [routeName] and then disposing the previous route once the new route has finished animating in.

**`popAndPushNamed`**

> Pop the current route off the navigator and push a named route in its place.

Answer (score 48):

Just a shorter answer.

The difference is only in the **animation** flutter executes.

- **pushReplacementNamed** -->> "enter animation"
- **popAndPushNamed** -->> "exit animation"

---

User A R post this also in his answer.

> pushReplacementNamed will execute the enter animation and popAndPushNamed will execute the exit animation.

---

Answer (score 3):

In pushReplacementNamed, the current route of the navigator pushes the route named [routeName] and then dispose of the previous route once the new route has finished animating
Whereas in popAndPushNamed, the current route gets popped out first then the new route gets pushed in it does not wait for the animation of the other route to get completed

Comment: Might hit help to add some examples to further emphasise the difference?

Answer (score 2):

@A R's explanation was great, but it was not a practical answer.

Unless there is only one stack, the effects of the two are perfectly the same.

This is because the app is terminated when popPushedNamed is used when the stack is 1.

And as @encubos said, the animation effect seems to be different.